# How to center "center of div" and not "starting point" of div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image]
<sub>(source: [ctrlv.in](http://img.ctrlv.in/51305a45c3aa8.jpg))</sub>

I am facing this issue in my responsive design website,when i reduce the width of the browser less than approx 700 pixels.

i added `margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;`,but the output remain unchanged.If i put left:50%,it shows some weird perhaps position because my header is `postion:fixed`(though i have not mentioned its top/left/right/bottom anywhere else).

The logo "ilovetrolls" starts from the center of the page....and hence the center of the image is not centered.[The page](https://ilovetrollstestbeta.blogspot.com/2012/12/top-14-funniest-pictures-of-day.html)
[image]
<sub>(source: [ctrlv.in](http://img.ctrlv.in/51305a532c7fd.jpg))</sub>

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove this style

```
#header {
    text-align: center;
}
```

placed inline line no 428 in media only screen width 767

Comment: i just see your code i i found that 
i dont know much css 
its just hit and try in browser's inspect element

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `display` property of the `#topdiv1` (on line 663) to `display: block`. I fiddled around in my Chrome web inspector and got it to work that way. Couldn't hurt to set the `float` to `float: none` either.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<style>
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  /* To see the affect of the above; not part of centering implementation. */
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 200px;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  Hello, world!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take `div.#topdiv3` and remove `float: left` and add in `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`. Then move `div.#topdiv3` outside of `div.#outter-wrapper`

[image]